# Swift scrolling controller for list of buttons

Tags: swift, macos, button, checkbox

I'm building a macOS app that requires a scrollable (and ideally, drag and reorderable) list of check box buttons. These buttons are going to be loaded in from a .plist file, so I need some control to load them into.

I'm really a c# programmer, and would just use a stackpanel or dockpanel or something of the like. Is there an equivalent in swift? Or do I need to write a custom control?

I have tried using various types of table views with check box cells, as well as rule views and other scrolling type views.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Sorry, I should have linked to [NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionview) and [NSStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstackview) for MacOS — it's obviously not part of UIKit. :)

//

Check out [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview). Similar to UITableView (data source, delegate, UIScrollView subclass), but more flexible on how the layout looks and acts. It also supports reordering.

You could also use a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview), but you would have to put it in a UIScrollView yourself and it doesn't easily support reordering.

Comment: This is on macOS, not iOS.

Comment: I thought UICollectionView was available on MacOS. Apologies.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Looks like a nice control to use

Comment: Updated with NSCollectionView and NSStackView.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using that later on today and follow up if I have questions!